# unexpected token error: in bookmarklet 

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

The idea is to write a simple bookmarklet.
If the question is a possible duplicate kindly point me to it, because i was unsuccessful in finding.

I'm trying to make the current page jquery enabled using the bookmarklet and use certain jquery apis.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

The above it the error I get using the below sample bookmarklet

```
javascript:(function(){
 var d=document.createElement('script');
 d.setAttribute('src', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js');
 document.head.appendChild(d);
 $('a').each(function(){
  alert( $(this).attr('src') );
 });
})()
```

​ If I execute the same code line-by-line in console it works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ahh, possibly because when you run it, jQuery hasn't been loaded yet. When you put break points, you give it more time

Comment: @JibiAbraham: While true, that cannot cause a SyntaxError.

Comment: yea, ideally should not cause a SyntaxError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the page wait until jQuery is fully loaded, add a load handler to the `script` element. This worked in my browser:

```
javascript:(function(){
 var d=document.createElement('script');
 d.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js';
 d.onload = function(){ /* load handler here */
   $('a').each(function(){
     console.log( $(this).attr('href') );
   });
 };
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(d);
})()
```

I changed your code a little bit (add the `src` attribute directly as property to the created `script` element, retrieve the `head` element in a more classical way, use `console.log` instead of `alert` and log the `href` attribute of all links).